# How to set the Docker IP the same as your computer (local) IP address

Tags: docker, virtualbox, portforwarding

I have just spent some hours to find a solution to my problem :

**The problem :**
I want to host a FTP server (in Docker) on my computer and I want to have access to it from a classic server on an other computer of the same network.
So when I'm connecting (in ftp) to my computer IP address, I want to have access to the ftp server running in Docker on this computer.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution**
It was hard to find an answer but after trying all possibilities, I found a simple one :

- Open : Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
- Select the VM used by docker (by default it's "default")
- Right click on it -> close -> shutdown
- Right click on it (again) -> settings -> Network -> card 1 -> advanced -> ports forwarding
- Now you click in the right top corner (+) to add a forwarding rule
- Give it the name you want (for me it was "ftp")
- Choose a protocol (for me it was TCP cause FTP use TCP)
- Let the 2 IP fields empty (to let default)
- Set the 2 ports (for me it was 21, cause is the standard ftp port)
- Press OK
- OK again
- That's it, you just have to (re)start docker and for the port you chose, you can use the IP address of your computer (which is running (the ftp server in) docker)

---

I think the solution can help some people, it's why I post it here.

*(and a big thanks to [Davey Chu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/6045465) who help me to fix this problem)*