# How to get from Android Emulator to Docker Machine's container?

Tags: android, docker, android-emulator, boot2docker

I have a Windows laptop with Docker Toolbox installed. So my backend services live in docker containers. 
Also, I have an Android Emulator with client application installed.

I know that I can get from Android Emulator to host's loopback by using 10.0.2.2 address. The problem is, that docker machine has its own address: 192.168.99.100 ( by default ).

How to make this work? Basically, I want to call 192.168.99.100:8080 from the Emulator. It is working well from Postman installed on Windows, but as far as I understand these are completely different networks, and this is the reason that it does not work out of the box.

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox for both Android emulation and Docker?

Comment: I am using the default stack from Android Studio. I've check in VirtualBox if Emulator is using VirtualBox, and it seems it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found two solutions:

**VirtualBox port forwarding**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/5076865 - 
After that you can access the docker app via `10.0.2.2:<your_port>`

**VirtualBox bridged adapter**

Open docker-machine setting in VirtualBox and enable the 3rd network adapter and set it to the bridge mode. You should be able to access the docker app via `192.168.99.100:<your_port>` directly from emulator.

For me the second solution is better, because I have `<your_port>` free on my docker host.