# Access a webserver inside a docker container from outside

Tags: tomcat, docker, webserver, containers, port

I want to access my tomcat webserver which is running inside a docker container from another computer.

For now I have a docker-compose.yml file which I start with the command `docker-compose up -d`

```
tomcat:
    image: tomcat
    ports:
        - "8000:8080"
    volumes:
        - ./CloudComputing.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/CloudComputing.war
    links: 
        - mongo
mongo:
    image: mongo
```

What do I have to change for accessing the webserver from another computer?

Docker Client Version: 17.03.1-ce

Comment: Probably this post can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo

Comment: thanks man you helped me a lot - the second answer was it