# Run docker container on localhost via VM

Tags: docker, containers

I'm new to Docker and Containers, and I'm trying to run a simple asp.net web app in a container but running into issues. My OS is Windows 10 Home, so I have to use the Docker Toolbox, which runs on a VM that only includes a basic Linux OS. When I spin up the container, it seems to start fine, but I can't view the app on the localhost.

$ docker run -p 8342:5000 -it jwarren:project

Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://*:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                    NAMES
98cc4aed7586        jwarren:project     "dotnet run"        8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes               0.0.0.0:8342->5000/tcp   naughty_brattain

I've tried several different recommendations that I found on the web, but none have helped so far. However, my knowledge of networking is very limited, so maybe I'm not fully understanding what needs to be done. I've tried accessing it with the default VM machine IP and the container IP. I understand that the port forwarding does not carry over to the container. Any assistance would be great, as this project is due on Tuesday, and this is the last road block before finishing.

Comment: try access http://127.0.0.1:8342

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following post that was really helpful: [How to connect to a docker container from outside the host (same network) [Windows]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo). Following the steps below worked perfectly:

1. Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager
2. Select the VM used by Docker
3. Click Settings -> Network Adapter 1 should (default?) be "Attached
   to:NAT"
4. Click Advanced -> Port Forwarding Add rule: Protocol TCP, Host Port
   8080, Guest Port 8080 (leave Host IP and Guest IP empty)

You should now be able to browse to your container via localhost:8080 and your-internal-ip:8080.

Started up the container (Dockerfile EXPOSES 5000):
docker run -p 8080:5000 -it jwarren:project

Was able to connect with http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to consider when working with a VM networking.

Virtual Box has 3 types of networking options NAT, Bridged and Host Only.

- NAT would allow your VM to access internet through your internet. But won't allow your HOST machine to access the VM
- Host Only network will create a network where the VM can reach the host machine and the Host can reach the VM. No internet using this network
- Bridged network will allow your VM to assign another IP from your Wifi router or the main network. This IP will allow VM to have net access as well as access to other machines on the network. This will allow even the host machine to reach the IP

Now in most cases when you want to run Docker inside a VM and access that VM using the host machine you want the VM to have both NAT and Host only bridges

Now accessing your app on port `8342` needs few things checked

- seliunx, firewalld, ufw are disabled on your VM (or properly configured to allow the port)
- Your VM has a host only network or bridged network
- `iptables -S` should not show REJECT rules

Some VMs come pre-configure to only allow port 22 from external network. So you should try access the app on `<hostonlyip>:8342` or `<bridgedip>:8342`.

If you want to test if the app is up or not you can do the following

```
docker inspect <containerid> | grep IPA
```

Get the IP from this and run the command

```
curl http://<containerip>:5000/
```

This command needs to be execute inside the VM and not on your machine. If this command doesn't work then your container is not listening on 5000. Sometimes app listen to only `127.0.0.1` inside the container. This means they will work only inside the container and not outside. The app inside the container needs to listen to `0.0.0.0`

If nothing works you can try an ssh tunnel approach

```
ssh -L 8342:127.0.0.1:8342 user@<VMIP>
```

And then you should be able to access the app on `localhost:8342`

Comment: Thanks for the quick and thorough response! I'll give it a shot when I get home and comment how it goes.