# Error when trying to carry out operations in hyperledger composer rest API

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I set up a persistent and secured REST server using Docker for a hyperledger composer business network as of this tutorial: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

However when I try to carry out any commands on the RESTful APi I get the following error:

`Unhandled error for request GET /api/Contract: Error: Error trying login and get user Context. Error: Error trying to enroll user or load channel configuration. Error: Calling enrollment endpoint failed with error [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:7054]`

Does anyone know whats causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have to change the endpoint IP address since you are dockerizing the REST API, it will stop being all services on the same machine so, when contacting 127.0.0.1:7054, it will end up as UNREACHABLE cause that service is not inside docker container.

To fix this, change 127.0.0.1 IP to your HOST machine IP (i.e 192.168.0.2) and try again. Also make sure, that if you use docker and you want to have services available from outside container, you have to map container ports.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sergio. Sorry but I'm having a little difficulty understanding what you meant. Do you mean - change the URL for the CA in the connection.json (/Users/simonmullaney/.composer/cards/admin@block-aviation-n‌etwork/connection.js‌on) to the address of the Docker container running the CA? 

I don't know what file the 127.0.0.1 IP is set in?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, is this all on a local development environment ? As specified in the sample connection profile [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/connectionprofile.html) - the CA server is meant to be listening on port 7054. So the problem is it can't contact your CA server to verify the identity of the REST /GET request. Not sure if you have any [docker networking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408403/run-docker-container-on-localhost-via-vm) either. Indeed check that all your fabric is up and running with `docker ps`. Assume you're doing this as a non-privileged user and installed Composer globally with `npm install` as a non-privileged user.

Comment: I have them all running in Docker containers. I had to change the addresses of the url in the connection profile (/Users/simonmullaney/.composer/cards/admin@block-aviation-network/connection.json) from 'http://localhost:7054' to 'http://172.18.0.4:7054' so that the composer-rest-server would work correctly - where 172.18.0.4 was the address of the docker container running my CA - If I left the fields as they were with localhost the rest server wasnt able to Discovering types from business network definition. I checked docker ps and all my containers are still running.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that docker instances are live.
The first time you start up a new runtime, you'll need to run the start script, then generate a PeerAdmin card

```
cd ~/fabric-tools
./startFabric.sh
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
```

Reference: [starting hyperledger fabric](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools.html)