# how to call service which is running inside docker container from my localhost ? in windows machine

Tags: docker, spring-boot, dockerfile, docker-machine, boot2docker

Here it is my Dockerfile

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8

ADD target/demo.jar demo.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","demo.jar"]
```

It is running inside the docker container. when i run `curl -v http://192.168.99.100:8080` in the docker window, It shows the result.
But when I run in browser , It is not working. I have tried both `http://192.168.99.100:8080` and `http://localhost:8080`. How to connect my docker ip from browser?

Comment: Can you please update your answer with your docker run command, try also looking into your Docker logs, what does the logs state?

Comment: I have tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/8295908 . Now It works Fine.

Comment: Thanks @RavinduFernando

Answer (score 0):

1.Open Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager

2.Select the VM used by Docker

3.Click Settings -> Network

4.Adapter 1 should (default?) be "Attached to: NAT"

5.Click Advanced -> Port Forwarding

6.Add rule: Protocol TCP, Host Port 8080, Guest Port 8080 (leave Host IP and Guest IP empty)

Guest is your docker container and Host is your machine
You should now be able to browse to your container via localhost:8080 and your-internal-ip:8080.

Reference:-->Yes I have found the answer in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/8295908. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please refer the place you got your answer from, Don't just copy paste the answer of some one else without acknowledgment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/4334340

Comment: Yes. I jus tell the answer. I have replied your comment itself.