# Access a docker container running on a VM machine from LAN connected PC

Tags: docker, virtualization, docker-toolbox, google-earth-engine

I want to run a Google Earth Engine Datalab on a server and access it from another PC on LAN. Server's OS is Windows Server 2012. So, following https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install-datalab-local, I did:

1. Install Docker Toolbox
2. Define a Local Workspace
3. Create the container, but changing: `-p "127.0.0.1:8081:8080"` for `-p "8081:8080"`. This is the full command:

`docker run -it -p "8081:8080" -v "$WORKSPACE:/content" -e "PROJECT_ID=$GCP_PROJECT_ID" $CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME` (see the link

It works, and I can access it through `192.168.99.100:8081`. But that only works for localhost, so I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/2791453, did all steps, and now I open a browser on the server, and access the Datalab through `196.168.0.55:8081` (that's the server LAN address), but I cannot access it from another computer connected to LAN.

Comment: it could be problem with firewall, router, or other, can you `ping 196.168.0.55` from the other LAN host?

Comment: yes, I can `ping`

Comment: is the port open to the host? what is output of `nc -z 196.168.0.55 8081 -v`?

Comment: @MazelTov `nc: connect to 196.168.0.55 port 8081 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out`

Comment: what should I allow through the firewall? VirtualBox?

Comment: i would say it is firewall issue on the windows host, try to disable it temporarly and see if it works

Comment: Yes! you were right! it was the firewall, I added a rule for port 8081 and it works! post your answer and I accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like firewall issue.
you can test networking is working OK from other host with `ping`

```
ping 196.168.0.55
```

if it is OK you can test if the port is open with `netcat`

```
nc -z 196.168.0.55 8081 -v
```

if it says **open port** it means there will be issue inside docker container, if it timeout or other error it will be firewall related