# How to access a server(which is running in a docker container) from other machine?

Tags: python, docker

I'm new to docker. I have deployed a python server in a docker container. And I'm able to access using my python application from my machine using virtual machine IP(192.168.99.100).

Ex: http://192.168.99.100:5000

How do I access my the application from the other machine which is in the same network?

I tried giving my machine IP but didn't work.

I run the application using "*docker run -p 5000:80 myPythonApp*"

Comment: this might be the desired solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/36458215/5284996

Answer (score 0):

An easy way out would be to forward port from your host machine to the virtual machine.

Solution may differ w.r.t the VM providers & Host OS that you use. Like for vagrant you can do something as below -
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html