# How to access dockerized app on remote host

Tags: r, docker, virtualbox, shinyproxy

I have dockerized shinyproxy app and I can reach it through `http://localhost:8080`. But I cant reach it outside the host computer.

- I tried `http://my-ip-adress:8080`
- I allowed port 8080 through windows firewall
- I read comments on port forwarding through VM [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo). But I am using ubuntu 20. 04 in windows 10 and there is no VM running so I dont know how to do port forwarding.
- I tried to run container  `docker run -itdp 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 shinyproxy-example`

But none of them worked.

At the end of the day I wanna get an address put it in an iframe then a website eventually. Am I missing a step or is there another way to do this?

I an new in docker and webdeveloping so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your (win10) firewall? In ubuntu are you using ufw? (I'm inferring WSL, is that true?) Is your goal to have an internet-facing app accessible through `shinyproxy`?

Comment: I tried it through windows firewall followed this https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html and I runned sudo ufw status and it says Status: inactive.  Yes something like this https://tugberkkaya.shinyapps.io/zxdb/