# How to access container running in Docker from outside of my PC

Tags: docker, networkx, docker-desktop, docker-network

I am using Docker desktop in Windows.

Now I am running rabbitmq inside docker.
I can access the rabbitMq using localhost:5672 from my browser.

However, when I try to access the rabbitMq from my mobile device's browser using:

host-computer-ip:5672, it doesn't work.
My mobile device is connected to the same network using wifi.

But, if I run the rabbit standalone (not inside docker), then I can reach it from my mobile's browser using host-computer-ip:5672

Here is my docker-compose:

```
rabbit:
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    image: rabbitmq:3
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15692:15692"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to connect to a docker container from outside the host (same network) \[Windows\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am using docker desktop, not virtualbox

Comment: @Junaed hi, im having the same issue. did you find a solution yet?