# Running OPC Server in a Docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, portforwarding, opc-ua

I have a OPC Server created using the .net SDK running in a separate docker container inside a multi-docker environment. I want to use the IP Address of the Host Machine in the OPC UA Endpoint URL.

So I gave

```
ServerConfiguration.BaseAddresses = "opc.tcp://10.132.142.12:4840/OPCUA/abb",
```

Where `10.132.142.12` is the IP address of my Host Machine. Then I also have published and mapped the `4840` port of the docker container to Host port. (Because of architecture restrictions I am not allowed to use Host Networking in my Docker Container)

Now when I try to connect to this OPC Server from UA Expert using the Endpoint URL `opc.tcp://10.132.142.12:4840/OPCUA/abb` I am not able to connect to it. In the Logs I get:

[image: servernode]

How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe docker containers have also have a local ip (something like 172.18.0.25) have you tried connecting from the host pc that ip. And does that work?

Comment: When I ping the Docker IP it works @VictorPieper

Comment: What is the entire `docker run ...` you used?

Comment: I use docker-compose and this is how my service is defined

  hubadapteropcua:
    container_name: hubadapteropcua
    image: imageName
    user: userName
    logging:
      driver: journald
      options:
        tag: Tagname
    restart: always
    env_file:
    - env/base
    - env/hubadapteropcua
    ports:
    - 4840:4840
    - 20041:5000
    volumes:
    - additionalIodds:/app/additionalIodd
    - /etc/ssl/certs:/etc/ssl/certs:ro
    extra_hosts:
    - "invalid.invalid:169.254.42.1"

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814696/how-to-connect-to-a-docker-container-from-outside-the-host-same-network-windo)** might help